# processAot fails on bean definition from Kotlin bean DSL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graalvm, spring-native, spring-bean-dsl

I have bean DSL as follows:

```kotlin
class BeansInitializer : ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {
    override fun initialize(applicationContext: GenericApplicationContext) {
        beans {
            bean {
                ref<Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder>().build()
            }
            // ...
```

When in `processAot` I get the following exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    Code generation is not supported for bean definitions declaring an instance supplier callback : 
    Root bean: class [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodNames=null; destroyMethodNames=null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.<init>(BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly and surprisingly, this functionality is not supported in Spring.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29555